# CHECK PHP SESSION - ISSET($SESSION - IS NOT WORKING

Tags: php, session, authentication

This is in my page, and it should check that a user is logged in on
http://carbonyzed.co.uk/Websites/Jason/sites/2/test/login_success.php

but anybody can assess it, not just those logged in

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION["myusername"]) ){
header("location:main_login.html");
}
?>
```

I have tried

**if( isset($_SESSION["myusername"]) ){**

and

**if( isset($_SESSION[$myusername]) ){**

**LOGIN CODE** perhaps a session isn't being created?

```
<?php

ob_start();
$host="ClubEvents.db.9606426.hostedresource.com"; // Host name 
$username="ClubEventsRead"; // Mysql username 
$password="Pa55word!"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="ClubEvents"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: session_register() is depreciated as of php version 5.3 and removed from php version 5.4. So please dont use it anymore.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php

Comment: Thanks for posting valid DB credentials and the hostname of your server. You should probably pick a stronger password than `password` for your `Administrative` user, and also look into at least *salting* the password instead of storing it as a plain MD5. Lastly, don't just edit the credentials out of this post, they'll still be in the edit log. You have to change them on the server. Also, if you store `member` passwords as plain text you'll be eaten by rabid goats in the night.

Comment: ye its a test database, my actual DB is different

Comment: i wanted to add it so that people can test it if they feel neccecary

Comment: Your funeral. I wouldn't expose even a read-only mySQL account like this to the internet if you *paid me*.

Comment: why? if the database is going to be deleted after?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 16):

Add the NOT operator `!` to the if statement. Also don't forget to add `exit()` after your header. The `location` header is telling the browser to redirect, but an attacker could view your page and simply ignore the `location` header, thus bypassing your authentication system becuase your PHP code would continue to execute.

```
if( !isset($_SESSION["myusername"]) ){
    header("location:main_login.html");
    exit();
}
```

Furthermore, you aren't calling `session_start()` in the login code that you posted, therefore  the session is not accessible.

Comment: +1 for remembering to put exit, doh on me =oP.

Comment: Add `session_start();` to your other page and change the if statement to as shown.

Comment: +2 i double @crypticツ comment, i almost tear all of my hair due to that, and just when few hair left, i see the exit() note here :)

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
{
    header('Location: main_login.html');
}

?>
```

You need to negate the check.

Comment: ok, I used this, and now it won't login - possibly, my login isnt creating a session perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
    header('Location: main_login.html');
}

?>
```